# Expo import of Pressable throws invariant violation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am developing an app using expo and was trying to style my button. However, it was suggested in another stack overflow question to switch to TouchableOpacity and on the [react-native TouchableOpacity page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity.html) they suggest to switch to a future proof solution called Pressable. Now I am trying to implement the Pressable component in my component like they have on the [react-native Pressable page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) and my code looks like this:

```
import { View, Text, Button, Pressable } from 'react-native';

export default function OrderDetail( {someProps} ){
.
.
.
<Pressable
    onPress={() => {
    setCategoryName('information')
    }}
    style={({ pressed }) => [
    {
        backgroundColor: pressed
        ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
        : 'white'
    },
    styles.wrapperCustom
    ]}>
    {({ pressed }) => (
    <Text style={styles.text}>
        {pressed ? 'Pressed!' : 'Press Me'}
    </Text>
    )}
</Pressable>
.
.
.
}
```

but I am getting this error:[image: the thrown error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressable is not available in Expo yet, because expo does not support React Native v0.63 (yet).

Comment: Expo SDK 39 was released with React Native 0.63.3 (on their latest update, sdk-39.0.3)